# CABAC for image compression

Tags: encoding, compression, lossless-compression

CABAC (Context Adaptive Binary Arithmetic Coding) is an advanced version of simple arithmetic encoding. Also according to many sources it is stated that it provides better compression rate as compared to simple arithmetic encoding. However, it is used more for video compression for example in H.264 and AIC.
My question is why it is not used for other compression tasks like image and audio?

Comment: It is, FLIF is based on CABAC